# Iambic Pentameter Help

Tags: writing-style

I'm certainly no expert on iambic pentameter. I actually just got the basic idea of it yesterday on https://poemshape.wordpress.com But, unfortunately, i still am not sure on how to tell whether or not something actually **is** in proper iambic pentameter or is an acceptable variant. One example i would like to know for certain if it is done correctly is a line from a King Los song. 
The line goes like this : "I **hav**n't, been **ama**teur, **ev**er, **nev**er. **Iam**bic pen**tam**eter, **clev**er, **bet**ter."

The bold parts being the stressed syllables. And i'm not entirely sure how to tag this post so if i do something wrong, correct me so i can fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I **hav**en't been **am**a-teur, **ev**er, **ne**ver.
>   I**amb**ic pen**tam**e-ter, **cle**ver, **bet**ter.

Based on your given emphasis, the first thing you can tell is that there are only 4 stressed syllables per line, so it cannot be pentameter (penta = 5); it is some form of tetrameter.

The second thing is that an iamb consists of exactly 2 syllables; the first is unstressed and the second stressed, "da-DA".  (Some examples of iambic words: "confer", "inflate", "depress".)  Since the rhythm clearly starts out with a three-syllable pattern, "da-DA-da", it also cannot be iambic.  In fact, this particular stress pattern is called an [amphibrach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamb_(poetry)).

The fact that the lines deviate from strict adherence to the amphibrach does not significantly alter the intended meter; you simply give a slight pause or extension to the prior syllable to cover the missing element.

A sample of proper iambic pentameter would be

> To **strive**, to **seek**, to **find**, and **not** to **yield**. *( (Alfred Tennyson, "Ulysses")*

I suggest you read the linked page at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamb_(poetry)) for more details.

To answer your question directly about how to tell if something is iambic pentameter (or a reasonably acceptable variation):

- First, count the stressed syllables; if you can't come up with a way to reasonably get 5 stresses, it cannot be pentameter.
- Then listen to the rhythm of the stressed and unstressed; they should alternate, or very nearly so (sometimes an extra syllable just has to be thrown in or left out to make the grammar work).  So the total syllable count per line should ideally be 10, but might be 9 or 11.  If there's more than one unstressed syllable per stressed syllable, it cannot be iambic.
- Finally, the (vast) majority of lines should start with an unstressed syllable and end with a stressed one.   If it routinely goes the other way around (Stressed-to-unstressed), it's a trochee, not an iamb.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification dude! shame that the writer wasn't actually rapping about iambic pentameter IN iambic pentameter.